# Which files are needed for DataTables to work on an html page>

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am trying to get DataTables to work correctly on a page so that it looks like [this](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/tables.html). I do not get any of the sorting, pagination or row limiting functionality that DataTables provides and I have a suspicion that is is because I am missing one of the files I need, or have included them in the wrong order.

CSS at the top of the page:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

JS at the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell whether or not I'm missing something, or if the DataTables javascript files are dependent on others I haven't  included?

(Note, I am using Bootstrap in the style of the [sb-admin-2](http://file:///C:/Users/a210045/Documents/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2-1.0.7/pages/index.html) template, but am not working directly off the template files, and so don't have the same folder structure as the template)

Comment: is the path correct for css & js files?

Comment: I just found out what was wrong. The paths were all correct, but I was calling the `$('#table').dataTable();` BEFORE loading any of the scripts, and so obviously it had no effect. It's my first time using Layout files (MVC 4) and didn't realise that it was being executed before the scripts were being loaded at the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

I seem to keep having these false alarms. As I mentioned in G.L.P's comment, this was the problem:

The paths were all correct, but I was calling `$('#table').dataTable();` BEFORE loading any of the scripts, and so obviously it had no effect. It's my first time using Layout files (MVC 4) and didn't realise that it was being executed before the scripts were being loaded at the end of the page.

To fix this, I moved including the scripts to the top of the Layout page. I know that it is recommended to put scripts at the bottom of the page, but at this point I cannot think of another work-around